# Problem validating in SSIS XML Task

Tags: xml, ssis, xsd

I have an XML file that I'm trying to validate against an XSD file in an SSIS XML Task.  The XSD does do a handful of imports and includes to other files and utilizes multiple namespaces.  I have opened these all in VS2005 and verified that no errors occur when validating the file there.  However, when I execute my SSIS package, it does not appear to be seeing anything in the external files (the files that are imported from the "Second Operand" XSD file).  Given that I can validate them in VS2005, I'm assuming I do not have any namespace or external filename conflicts/errors within the XSD files.  Is there any limitation in SSIS using multiple linked XSD files or multiple namespaces?  I've added the linked XSD files to the connection manager but that didn't seem to help either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used some very simple examples to run through SSIS and it does not appear to support multiple schema documents.